# What is the Samsung s3 user-agent?

Tags: user-agent, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to find out what is the user agent of Samsung Galaxy S3.

I don't have the device so I can't test myself. The user agent is going to be recognized by my web server.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III this page contains all model number for s3 across all countries one can search for user string for all such models.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-gb; GT-I9300 Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

Comment: There isn't one userAgent for the entire series, they're different depending on carrier.

Comment: Mine shows up as SGH-I747M So is there any way to target all galaxy s3's? I find they bugout when it comes to setting the initial value for an <input type=datetime />. I need to make a device specific fix.

Comment: @Amrit: Look up the S3 on Wikipedia, there are different models sold. But it seems unlikely that the bug is unique to the S3. There's no reason for Samsung to customize Mozilla or the Webkit rendering engine just for the S3.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: You'd think. I work for a mobile commerce shop, and among the bug team, the S3 is infamous for requiring device-specific hacks for problems no other platforms have. I found this question chasing an S3-specific bug (that only occurs in the native browser) that makes me wish this phone could feel pain.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Your idea about bugs not being unique to individual versions of S3's is incorrect. I have confirmed that some are better at rendering SVG's than others.

Answer (score 1):

[What's My User Agent?](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) is a great tool for figuring out what the User Agent of your current browser is. Just navigate to it in the browser of whatever device you want the UA for.

If you don't have the device you want to test, that site also has a section for Common User Agents. Once you figure out the UA you want to test, you can use the [User Agent-Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) plug-in to have Chrome mimic that UA.

**Full Disclosure: I don't work for or know the people who have created these tools, just figured I'd share some of the tools I use with the community : )**

Answer (score 1):

- There's no such thing as the user agent for a specific device.
- The user agent depends on the client (e.g. a web browser) being used to access the web server
- The user agent also differs according to the running version of Android
- You need to at least look for the user agent string for a specific browser (e.g. the default Android browser, or Chrome)
- Also, apps in Android each run within their own VM, which is called 'Dalvik'. A Dalvik user agent string can be reported within an http header in some instances.