# Using JavaScript, how to detect if Samsung Galaxy Store is present on the visitor's device

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-intent, user-agent

I'm making a download button to be used in a HTML page. It will download app which is published on Samsung Galaxy Store.

Using JavaScript, I want to detect if user has Samsung Galaxy Store installed. If it's installed, I will redirect user to Galaxy Store, else will redirect them to our app's website.

If we find out if it's a Samsung device using UserAgent as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29229467/1136857), is it safe to assume that the device will always have Samsung Galaxy Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @snachmsm, detecting presence of Galaxy Store is not possible.

I could however find out if it's a Samsung device or not using following `userAgent` match condition:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/SAMSUNG|SGH-[I|N|T]|GT-[I|P|N]|SM-[N|P|T|Z|G]|SHV-E|SCH-[I|J|R|S]|SPH-L/i)) {
  alert("it's Samsung default browser");
  // your code for Samsung goes here
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29229467/1136857).

Since all Samsung devices will have Galaxy Store, it's adequate to have just `userAgent` match.

Answer (score 1):

for shure you can change UA, e.g. for `WebView` (`webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(...)`), there is also Firefox browser which can handle some plugins, including one which allow to change UA... so it isn't a reliable way to detect/restrict anything. in fact: there is no reliable way to detect native app presence from web-level. even more: [on newest Android OS version (API30) even native apps can't  check this presence (need additional permission now)](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)

Comment: It's OK if `userAgent` is changed by client (native app) or browser plugin. This will happen very rarely. Besides if `userAgent` is changed like this, it's better to show content for whatever userAgent they're requesting. Thanks for confirming that installed app detection is not possible.